# Android Location Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, location

I'm trying to retrieve the position of the device. unfortunately my code continues to generate exceptional but I can not figure out what creates the problem.
To take the position, I followed what was written in https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#play-services

Could anyone give me some advice?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}
//some other methods...
```

And this is the error i get during the execution:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.filippocalabrese.whereismycar, PID: 12436
>                                                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Looper;ILcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener;)V
>   in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzk; or its super
>   classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk'
>   appears in
>   /data/app/com.filippocalabrese.whereismycar-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes15.dex)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzb.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices$1.zzn(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices$1.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzvq(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.filippocalabrese.whereismycar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

I've tryed to Google it and search for a solution but i've had no luck at all :/

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I did not say that the exception is raised by the call to the build () method

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

I suspect the android version you are using is different from the tutorial you are following on. sometimes method signatures get updated along the versions. Please verify that you have the right version as the tutorial/article you are trying to use.